# use SWR with depending request data

Tags: reactjs, fetch, vercel, swr

I'm trying to use SWR to fetch list of users connected to the logged in user id provided by a custom hook.

I can't put `useSWR` inside either `useCallback` or `useEffect` or `if (loggedInAdvisor) { ... }`... Can't figure out how to do it.

```
export const fetchDetailedAdvisorPrognoses = (
  body: DetailedAdvisorPrognosesRequest
): Promise<DetailedAdvisorPrognoses[]> | null => {
  const accessToken = getFromPersistance(ACCESS_TOKEN)

  if (!accessToken) {
    return null
  }

  return fetch('https://x/api/v2/advisors/prognoses', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      ...generateDefaultHeaders(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: getAuthorizationHeader(accessToken),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  }).then(res => res.json())
}

function Workload(): ReactElement | null {
  const { loggedInAdvisor } = useAuthentication()

  // yesterday
  const fromDate = moment()
    .subtract(1, 'day')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  // 14 days ahead
  const toDate = moment()
    .add(13, 'days')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD')

  const { data, error } = useSWR<DetailedAdvisorPrognoses[] | null>('fetchWorkloadData', () =>
    'detailed',
    fetchDetailedAdvisorPrognoses({
      advisorIds: [loggedInAdvisor.id], // <-- I want to pause the query until loggedInAdvisor is defined 
      fromDate,
      toDate,
    })
  )

  // todo: display errors better
  if (error) {
    return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>
  }

  if (!data) {
    return <LoadingV2 isLoading={!data} />
  }

  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    // advisors prognoses is first element in data array
    const [first] = data
    const days: WorkloadDay[] = Object.keys(first.daysMap).map(date => ({
      date,
      value: first.daysMap[date],
    }))

    return <WorkloadLayout before={first.before} days={days} />
  }

  return null
}
```

Answer (score 21):

SWR supports [Conditional Fetching](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching#conditional), instead of using an `if` branching, you need to pass `null` as a key (that's the mental modal of React Hooks too):

```js
const { data, error } = useSWR(
  loggedInAdvisor ? 'fetchWorkloadData' : null,
  () => {...}
)
```

---

*Updated 2021/12/10*:

You can also fetch some data, that based on the result of another request using SWR, too:

```js
const { data: user } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher)
const { data: avatar } = useSWR(user ? '/api/avatar?id=' + user.id : null, fetcher)
```

In this case, if `user` isn't ready the second request will not start since the key will be `null`. When the first request ends, the second one will start naturally. This is because a **re-render** will always happen when `user` changes from `undefined` to some data.

You can use this method to fetch as many dependent resources as you want, with the best possible parallelism.

Comment: What is missing to me is to have 'real' dependent data. I.e. if you need to make a fetch some result asynchronously, after which you will use the result as a parameter  in the swr fetcher.

Comment: @html_programmer You can do it with SWR too, I just updated my answer (it's also mentioned in the docs linked).

Comment: This will work; cool!

Comment: @ShuDing can you please check this similar issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557556/client-side-data-fetching-with-swr-from-internal-api-route